# How do I modify existing resource via ARM

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have VM which was not deployed through ARM and I would like to add some additional information to this VM (like `tag` for example). I can not find any examples how to approach this situation. Any links or explanation in nutshell how this shall be accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to generate / export the existing RM template, you can do this using the following guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template

1. Go to the Resource Group
2. Click Automation Script

Alternatively, you can go to https://resources.azure.com to extract RM templates for existing resources.

Then, the next step is to modify it based on your needs, e.g. to add the tags.

Comment: This generates template file with empty parameters list, so it require manual input bunch of existing resources (like existing storage account etc) which will not be modified. I really hoped there is away just define changes in ARM template and just leave all the rest stuff in place which is not required to be changed. Actual VM is generated from ASR and not through ARM template and hence issues comes up whether to use Powershell or ARM for modification and I assumed ARM is prefered choice but I can not see a easy way to modify existing resources without essentially starting from scratch

Comment: Sure, you can create just a small resource with the bare minimum: a resource for your VM, the name, and then the tags you want to add. As long as you do an Incremental update (the default) it will be fine.